# Creating EXTERNAL Table on Hive for Azure Blob with credentials

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, hive, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

We have quite a few storage accounts in `s3` and now in `wasb (azure blob)`. 
I provide `access` and `secret` keys for s3 when I `EXTERNAL TABLE` like below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table_S3
(
col1                      string,
col2                      string
)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION 's3a://*ACCESS_KEY*:*SECRET_KEY*@bucket_name/direc_name/'
tblproperties ("orc.comlress"="ZLIB");
```

How do I achive this in Blob?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table_WASB
(
col1                      string,
col2                      string
)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION 
'wasb://container_name@STORATE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/direc_name/'
tblproperties ("orc.comlress"="ZLIB");
```

I want to set my storage access key here in the create table syntax, so that I can access multiple storage accounts and not define the credentials in core-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table_WASB ( col1
>   string, col2                      string ) STORED AS ORC LOCATION 
>   'wasb://container_name@STORATE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/direc_name/'
>   tblproperties ("**orc.compress**"="ZLIB");

It should be correct.

Probably you need to give access to your service principal to save data on that storage or access to your storage explorer (from portal.azure) > container > access and allow for user is executing that query (your service principal).

If you use hdinsights you can share the specific error with us.